# How to pass a json array of type object to MVC controller class

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass through a JSON array through to my controller. I want to be able to post data to the database from a JSON array which is populated and passed to the controller through javascript in the client side. However, it is not receiving anything in the controller. My controller received a null value as the parameter.

The following is my controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [SiteAuthorize]
    public ActionResult SaveDashboard(List<Dashboard> dashboards)
    {
        try
        {

            string result = "";
            return Json(new { Result = result, Message = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "Error", Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

The following is my javascript:

```
    var dashboards = {
    "DashboardName": '',
    "Width": '',
    "Height": '',
       "DashboardCell": [
           {
               "DashCellId": '',
               "x": '',
               "y": '',
               "DashWidth": '',
               "DashHeight": '',
               "colspan": '',
               "rowspan": '',
               "Active": '',
               "CellValue": '',
               "cellClass": '',
               "previousElementSibling": ''
           }
        ]
    };

    var tablestructure = $("#TableStructure").val();
    var savename = document.getElementById("namedash").value;

    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var width = table.clientWidth;
    var height = table.clientHeight;
    var DashboardCell = [];
    dashboards.DashboardName = savename;
    dashboards.Width = width;
    dashboards.Height = height;
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
    {

        //iterate through rows
        //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < col.attributes.length; x++)
            {
                if (col.attributes[x].localName == "colspan") {
                    var colspan = col.attributes[x].value;
                }
                else if (col.attributes[x].localName == "rowspan") {
                    var rowspan = col.attributes[x].value;
                }
                else if (col.attributes[x].localName == "class")
                {
                    var cellClass = col.attributes[x].value;
                }
            }

            var res = col.id.split(", ");
            var x = parseInt(res[0]);
            var y = parseInt(res[1]);
            var DashHeight = col.clientHeight;
            var DashWidth = col.clientWidth;
            if (j > 0) {
                var previousElementSibling = col.previousElementSibling.id;
            }
            else {
                var previousElementSibling = '';
            }
            var DashCellID = col.id;
            var CellValue = col.innerText;
            var DashCell = { DashCellId: DashCellID, x: x, y: y, DashWidth: DashWidth, DashHeight: DashHeight, colspan: colspan, rowspan: rowspan, Active: 1, CellValue: CellValue, cellClass: cellClass, previousElementSibling: previousElementSibling };
            DashboardCell.push(DashCell);

            //iterate through columns
            //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
        }
    }
    dashboards.DashboardCell = DashboardCell;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/KPIReportAdmin/SaveDashboard',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { dashboards: JSON.stringify(dashboards) },
        success: function (result)
        {

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Failed");
        }

    });
```

The following is my class:

```
public class DashboardCell
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int colspan { get; set; }
    public int rowspan { get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public string CellValue { get; set; }
    public string DashCellId { get; set; }
    public string cellClass { get; set; }
    public int previousElementSibling { get; set; }
}

public class Dashboard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public List<DashboardCell> DashboardCell { get; set; }
}
```

I expect to receive the dashboard list in SaveDashboard but I'm getting null

Comment: Your variable name or data type may be mismatched. Please check that once.

Comment: you are sending `dashboards` as string, try sending the object itself (no stringify)

Comment: I'm getting the following network error: `Invalid JSON primitive: object.` when it is trying to access the controller. What could be causing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to pass the JS object as `List<T>` collection using AJAX:

1) Put `JSON.stringify` with the object itself and set `traditional: true` option, only single parameter should be set:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/KPIReportAdmin/SaveDashboard',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    traditional: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(dashboards),
    success: function (result)
    {

    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Failed");
    }
});
```

2) Pass the raw object without stringify-ing it by using `$.param()` function with `traditional: true` option:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/KPIReportAdmin/SaveDashboard',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $.param({ dashboards: dashboards }, true),
    success: function (result)
    {

    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Failed");
    }
});
```

The exception occurred because you're passing a JS object which containing JSON string with `data: { dashboards: JSON.stringify(dashboards) }` and controller action method doesn't know how to resolve it into `List<T>` collection object as parameter.

Related issue:

[Invalid JSON primitive: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776104/invalid-json-primitive-object)

Answer (score 1):

As I see the problem is in your JSON file. In your JSON you have a property called  "DashboardName" where in API its called "Name". Height, Width, UserID are INT, but your passing string to it.

try changing your values as below

```html
var dashboards = {
    "Name": "",
    "Width": 0,
    "Height": 0,
    "UserID": 0,
    "DashboardCell": [
    {
      "Width": 0,
      "Height": 0,
      "Active": false,
      "colspan": 0,
      "rowspan": 0,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "CellValue: "",
      "DashCellId: "",
      "cellClass: "",
      "previousElementSibling": 0
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found that in my controller I was passing through a list of Dashboard where I only needed to add `Dashboard dashboards` as the list is within the Dashboard class.

Also doing what Tetsuya Yamamoto suggested helped.

Thanks everyone!